# Несколько раз проверить наличие определенного элемента в массиве Json с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, json, postman

Есть массив

```
[
{
    "id": 1237,
    "status": "Started",
    "customer": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение города Москва \"Гимназия №4\"",
        "address": "г. Москва, ул. Строителей, д. 12, офис 6",
        "email": "info@acme.ru",
        "phone": "408-867-5309"
    },
    "condition": {
        "nameTRY": "Молоко питьевое пастеризованное, м.д жира 2.5%",
        "requirments": "ГОСТ 10705-80",
        "ordertype": "Закупка до 100 000 руб.  (п. 4 ст.93 Закона №44-ФЗ)",
        "ordersize": 100,
        "maxdate": "22.08.2018",
        "orderplan": "Опишите график поставки",
        "orderplace": 102,
        "pickupinstore": true,
        "pickupinstoredescription": "поле для ввода информации о возможном месте самовывоза заказчиком",
        "startprice": 1098,
        "oneprice": 10.98,
        "startfinalprice": 1098,
        "payterms": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию.",
        "licenseneeded": true,
        "additionaInfo": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию."
    },
    "offers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizations": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "TESTTEST",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "NEWORGANISATION",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Наименование документа",
            "filename": "table.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "organizationFinal": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Наименование организации",
        "email": "org@org.ru"
    },
    "proposals": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizationid": 1,
            "orderid": 1,
            "createdat": "2017-07-21T17:32:28"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 1238,
    "status": "Started",
    "customer": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение города Москва \"Гимназия №4\"",
        "address": "г. Москва, ул. Строителей, д. 12, офис 6",
        "email": "info@acme.ru",
        "phone": "408-867-5309"
    },
    "condition": {
        "nameTRY": "Молоко питьевое пастеризованное, м.д жира 2.5%",
        "requirments": "ГОСТ 10705-80",
        "ordertype": "Закупка до 100 000 руб.  (п. 4 ст.93 Закона №44-ФЗ)",
        "ordersize": 100,
        "maxdate": "22.08.2018",
        "orderplan": "Опишите график поставки",
        "orderplace": 102,
        "pickupinstore": true,
        "pickupinstoredescription": "поле для ввода информации о возможном месте самовывоза заказчиком",
        "startprice": 1098,
        "oneprice": 10.98,
        "startfinalprice": 1098,
        "payterms": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию.",
        "licenseneeded": true,
        "additionaInfo": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию."
    },
    "offers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizations": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "TESTTEST",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "NEWORGANISATION",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Наименование документа",
            "filename": "table.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "organizationFinal": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Наименование организации",
        "email": "org@org.ru"
    },
    "proposals": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizationid": 1,
            "orderid": 1,
            "createdat": "2017-07-21T17:32:28"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Необходимо проверить что в данном массиве в каждом разделе `offers - organizations` есть `id`  с нужным номером.

Необходимо для написания тестов в Postman. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Можете уточнить, как нужно проверять, задается какой-то id как параметр для функции и потом осуществляется проверка? И можете добавить результат проверки для данного json, чтобы было понятно что должно быть в ответе

Comment: Offers - это массив с данными о заказе в котором в объекте organizations указываются массивы с данными об отклинувшихся организациях у каждой из которой уникаьный Id. В данном примере - есть 2 Offers и мне например необходимо убедиться что в каждом из них есть орагнизация с id = 2. Соответственно в ответ я просто должен получить например false или true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу:

```js
let data = [
{
    "id": 1237,
    "status": "Started",
    "customer": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение города Москва \"Гимназия №4\"",
        "address": "г. Москва, ул. Строителей, д. 12, офис 6",
        "email": "info@acme.ru",
        "phone": "408-867-5309"
    },
    "condition": {
        "nameTRY": "Молоко питьевое пастеризованное, м.д жира 2.5%",
        "requirments": "ГОСТ 10705-80",
        "ordertype": "Закупка до 100 000 руб.  (п. 4 ст.93 Закона №44-ФЗ)",
        "ordersize": 100,
        "maxdate": "22.08.2018",
        "orderplan": "Опишите график поставки",
        "orderplace": 102,
        "pickupinstore": true,
        "pickupinstoredescription": "поле для ввода информации о возможном месте самовывоза заказчиком",
        "startprice": 1098,
        "oneprice": 10.98,
        "startfinalprice": 1098,
        "payterms": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию.",
        "licenseneeded": true,
        "additionaInfo": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию."
    },
    "offers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizations": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "TESTTEST",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "NEWORGANISATION",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Наименование документа",
            "filename": "table.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "organizationFinal": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Наименование организации",
        "email": "org@org.ru"
    },
    "proposals": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizationid": 1,
            "orderid": 1,
            "createdat": "2017-07-21T17:32:28"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 1238,
    "status": "Started",
    "customer": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение города Москва \"Гимназия №4\"",
        "address": "г. Москва, ул. Строителей, д. 12, офис 6",
        "email": "info@acme.ru",
        "phone": "408-867-5309"
    },
    "condition": {
        "nameTRY": "Молоко питьевое пастеризованное, м.д жира 2.5%",
        "requirments": "ГОСТ 10705-80",
        "ordertype": "Закупка до 100 000 руб.  (п. 4 ст.93 Закона №44-ФЗ)",
        "ordersize": 100,
        "maxdate": "22.08.2018",
        "orderplan": "Опишите график поставки",
        "orderplace": 102,
        "pickupinstore": true,
        "pickupinstoredescription": "поле для ввода информации о возможном месте самовывоза заказчиком",
        "startprice": 1098,
        "oneprice": 10.98,
        "startfinalprice": 1098,
        "payterms": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию.",
        "licenseneeded": true,
        "additionaInfo": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию."
    },
    "offers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizations": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "TESTTEST",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "NEWORGANISATION",
                    "email": "org@org.ru"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Наименование документа",
            "filename": "table.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "organizationFinal": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Наименование организации",
        "email": "org@org.ru"
    },
    "proposals": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
            "code": "o124",
            "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
            "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
            "price": 1098,
            "organizationid": 1,
            "orderid": 1,
            "createdat": "2017-07-21T17:32:28"
        }
    ]
}
]

function check(data, id) {
  return data.every( // возвращаем true, если нижеследующая функция возвращает true для всех элементов массива data
    item => item.offers.every( // аналогично, проверяем все элементы подмассива offers текущего элемента data
      offer => offer.organizations.some( // возвращаем true, если условие выполняется хотя бы для одного элемента подмассива organizations
        org => org.id == id // иными, словами, если есть элемент с id, равным переданному в функцию
      )
    )
  )
}

console.log(check(data, 2));
console.log(check(data, 5));
```

Используются методы [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) и [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

`some()` возвращает `true` если переданная в него функция возвращает true хотя бы для одного элемента массива, а `every()`, соответственно, для каждого элемента.

Comment: Очень похоже на правду, спасибо. А можно объяснить или где то почитать, как именно оно работает? Как определяет где искать и т.д.

Comment: Добавил комментарии, и пару строчек про используемые методы. :)

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо большое, очень полезно :) Правда в постмане почему-то вместо false возвращает пустое значение Х) Но попробую разобраться.

Comment: Если есть возможность, хотел бы попросить ещё немного помочь. Сейчас в начале массива добавилось :
      { "items":
 [ 
{ 
"id": 9002, ... 
     
. Не могу понять что именно нужно добавить что бы снова начал понимать. Пытался добавить 'items.every'

Comment: То есть сейчас вся эта структура стала полем `items` какого-то внешнего объекта (`let data = {items : [ {id : 9002,...}, ... ]}`)? Если так, то (на примере кода в этом ответе) либо надо добавить это в функцию `check()` : `return data.items.every(...)`, либо сразу при вызове передавать туда только нужный объект: `console.log(check(data.items, 2))`

Comment: @Drakon4eg Что-то вдруг подумалось, что возможно система Вас не оповестила о предыдущем комментарии, не уверен, в каких именно случаях посылаются уведомления, если не упоминается конкретный адресат. В общем, этот комментарий предназначен для того, чтобы уведомление точно было. :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Сейчас пытаюсь сделать по аналогии для поля `customer.id` из примера, но получаю `TypeError | item.customer.every is not a function` что я делаю не так?   
`function check2(data, id) {
  return data.items.every( 
    item => item.customer.every( 
cus => cus.id == id //
      )
    )
}`

Comment: @Drakon4eg Это потому что `every()` - это метод массива, а `customer` у Вас — не массив, а объект. Тут, насколько я понимаю, перебирать-то ничего не надо, у конкретного customer'а, всего одно поле id, его и надо проверять: `... return data.items.every( item => item.customer.id == id) ...`